# How add transformation to Camel http-balancer in Spring xml?

Tags: java, spring, http, apache-camel, load-balancing

I make http balancer through the Camel
(install JBoss Fuse befor
http://www.jboss.org/products/fuse/download/

```
%fuse_dir%=c:\temp\jboss-fuse-6.2.1.redhat-084
%path%=%path%;%fuse_dir%\bin;
```

)

```
git clone https://github.com/mishin/http-balancer-camel.git
cd http-balancer-camel/smx-ws-examples-jboss-fuse-6.2.1
mvn clean install
fuse console
```

in fuse console we write

```
JBossFuse:karaf@root> features:addurl mvn:com.fusesource.examples/ws-features/1.0-SNAPSHOT/xml/features
JBossFuse:karaf@root> features:install smx-ws-examples
JBossFuse:karaf@root> list | grep Examples
JBossFuse:karaf@root> log:Display
```

that start our testing services
now we have 3 services:
http://localhost:9091/greeterProxy?wsdl
http://localhost:9090/greeter?wsdl
http://localhost:9090/greeterImpl?wsdl

so we build balancer

```
git clone https://github.com/mishin/http-balancer-camel.git
cd http-balancer-camel/camel-gateway
mvn -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true camel:run
```

so short code is
https://github.com/mishin/http-balancer-camel/blob/master/camel-gateway/src/main/resources/META-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml

```
    <camelContext trace="false" id="greeterGateway" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
  <route id="proxyRoute">
    <from uri="jetty:http://localhost:9092/greeterProxy?matchOnUriPrefix=true"/>
    <loadBalance>
      <failover>
        <exception>java.io.IOException</exception>
      </failover>
      <to uri="jetty:http://localhost:9090/greeterImpl?bridgeEndpoint=true&amp;throwExceptionOnFailure=false"/>
      <to uri="jetty:http://localhost:9090/greeter?bridgeEndpoint=true&amp;throwExceptionOnFailure=false"/>
      <convertBodyTo type="java.lang.String"/>
    </loadBalance>
  </route>
</camelContext>
```

I make failover http-balancer
so if I call from web browser
http://localhost:9092/greeterProxy?wsdl
than I got

```
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:tns="http://impl.greeter.examples.fusesource.com/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:ns3="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" xmlns:ns1="http://examples.fusesource.com/greeter" name="ConcreteGreeterService" targetNamespace="http://impl.greeter.examples.fusesource.com/">
<wsdl:import location="http://localhost:9090/greeterImpl?wsdl=Greeter.wsdl" namespace="http://examples.fusesource.com/greeter"></wsdl:import>
<wsdl:binding name="ConcreteGreeterServiceSoapBinding" type="ns1:Greeter">
<soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
<wsdl:operation name="greetMe">
<soap:operation soapAction="" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input name="greetMe">
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output name="greetMeResponse">
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="pingMe">
<soap:operation soapAction="" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input name="pingMe">
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output name="pingMeResponse">
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
<wsdl:fault name="PingMeFault">
<soap:fault name="PingMeFault" use="literal"/>
</wsdl:fault>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="greetMeOneWay">
```

...
I need make transformation
change

```
<wsdl:output name="pingMeResponse">
```

to

```
<wsdl:output name="pingAnotherResponse">
```

I tyr it through
 simple transformation, for example

```
    <convertBodyTo type="java.lang.String" />
    <transform>
        <simple>${in.body.replaceAll("greet([A-Z])Response", "bar$1foo")}</simple>
    </transform>
```

full code is:

```
<camelContext trace="false" id="greeterGateway" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <route id="proxyRoute">
        <from uri="jetty:http://localhost:9092/greeterProxy?matchOnUriPrefix=true" />
        <loadBalance>
            <failover>
                <exception>java.io.IOException</exception>
            </failover>
            <to uri="jetty:http://localhost:9090/greeterImpl?bridgeEndpoint=true&amp;throwExceptionOnFailure=false" />
            <to uri="jetty:http://localhost:9090/greeter?bridgeEndpoint=true&amp;throwExceptionOnFailure=false" />
            <convertBodyTo type="java.lang.String" />
        </loadBalance>

        <convertBodyTo type="java.lang.String" />
        <transform>
            <simple>${in.body.replaceAll("greet([A-Z])Response", "bar$1foo")}</simple>
        </transform>

    </route>
</camelContext>
```

but it doesn't work at all
when I invoke http://localhost:9092/greeterProxy?wsdl
it doesn't replace

```
<wsdl:output name="pingMeResponse">
```

why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FailOverLoadBalancer uses async routing engine which means that your transform block doesn't hit the response. Try to use direct endpoints and put the transform code inside separate routes (from direct->to jetty-> transform). That should help.